# How to update a custom view in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-custom-view

I'm developing a simple custom View to show a gauge composed by a background image above which i print a number (rpm) and draw a pointer.
To achieve it I defined a class (MyGauge) that extends ImageView class. In the onDraw() member I drawLine() and drawText() a number sent by the activity and collected by SetRpm() member; then I force an invalidate() call.
The activity runs a Thread (a Runnable instance) to generate a different number every second; the thread dispatches a Message to the activity; the Handler receives the message and sets the number by SetRpm() function.

The error I receive is:

```
03-12 09:39:33.280 1796-1827/com.stemmo.termi_up W/dalvikvm: threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb178e678)
03-12 09:39:33.280 1796-1827/com.stemmo.termi_up E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-78
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:869)
at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4253)
at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10539)
at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10494)
at com.stemmo.termi_up.CustomViews.MyGauge.SetRpm(MyGauge.java:61)
at com.stemmo.termi_up.GaugeActivity$2.handleMessage(GaugeActivity.java:54)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at com.stemmo.termi_up.GaugeActivity$3.run(GaugeActivity.java:83)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

So, the handler is in the thread's context??
How can i solve it?
Do I need to AsyncTask object instead of the Runnable one?

Comment: Could you please put your code here to check the issue with your code ?

Comment: See the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view in Android can only be updated from the UI thread. You can always post a Runnable to a view like this

```
    MyGauge gauge = ... // your custom view
    gauge.post(new Runnable() {
        view.SetRPM();
    });
```

Comment: I solved with:    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                myGauge.SetRpm(nValue);
                            }
                        });

Answer (score 0):

I answer cause i better write down the code ..
This is the code on the onCreate() of the Activity:

```
       final Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            Bundle data = msg.getData();
            String v = data.getString("value");
            myGauge.SetRpm(v);
        }
    };

    // Simul thread
    nValue = 0;
    bUpDown = true;
    Runnable thread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if (bUpDown)    // Up
                   ...
                }

                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                data.putString("value", String.valueOf(nValue));
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.setData(data);
                myHandler.dispatchMessage(msg);

                // Delay
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(thread).start();
```

The SetRpm() member inside MyGauge is:

```
 public void SetRpm(String newRpm)
{
    m_strRpm = newRpm;
    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with your code. Please replace your code line

myHandler.dispatchMessage(msg); with myHandler.sendMessage(msg);

It will fix the Exception "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."